# Not able to pass data from html to python <a> tag

Tags: python, flask, backend

The user is given the option to select a mood from the list. This must be passed to the python for further process, but I am unable to do this. If someone can help, I will be really grateful.

Python code:

```
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/music/")
def music_page():
    return render_template("music_page_1.html")


@app.route("/music/generated_list/")
def music_page_2():
    global generated_list
    listGenerator = songListGenerator(mood_selected)
    generated_list = listGenerator.generate_list()
    return render_template("music_page_2.html")


@app.route("/music/generated_list/", methods=["GET"])
def music_page_2_1():
    global mood_selected
    # global generated_list

    mood_selected = request.form.get("mood")
    print(f"Selected Mood: {mood_selected}")

    # listGenerator = songListGenerator(mood_selected)
    # generated_list = listGenerator.generate_list()

    return render_template("music_page_2.html", generated_list=generated_list)

    # return redirect("/music/generated_list/result")


@app.route("/music/generated_list/connect_spotify/")
def music_page_3():
    global username
    username = request.form.get("user")

    return render_template("music_page_3.html")
```

HTML code:

```
<body>
    <form action="" method="get">
      <header>
        <div class="heading">
          <ul>
            <li id="devo" name="mood">
              <a href="#" onclick="submitForm('Devotional')">Devotional</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li id="hap" name="mood">
              <a href="/music/generated_list/" onclick="submitForm('Happy')">
                Happy
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li id="sad" name="mood">
              <a href="#" onclick="submitForm('Sad')">Sad</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li id="rel" name="mood">
              <a href="#" onclick="submitForm('Relaxing')">Relaxing</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul id="rom2">
            <li id="rom" name="mood">
              <a href="#" onclick="submitForm('Romantic')">Romantic</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul id="nos2">
            <li id="nos" name="mood">
              <a href="#" onclick="submitForm('Nostalgic')">Nostalgic</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </header>
      <footer>
        <div class="foot">
          <ul id="cel2">
            <li id="cel" name="mood">
              <a href="#" onclick="submitForm('Celebration')">Celebration</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul id="ene2">
            <li id="ene" name="mood">
              <a href="#" onclick="submitForm('Energetic')">Energetic</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </form>
    <div id="main">
      <h2>WHAT IS YOUR MOOD LIKE?</h2>
      <h4>DRAG THE PLAY BUTTON TO SET THE MOOD</h4>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Error message:
[image: error message]

Just for info:
I am making a website which generates a playlist of songs based on the user selected mood.